# Magento 2 CategoryFactory exclude current product from collection

Tags: magento2, product, collection, product-collection, registry

I am using an extension auto-selecting related products from the same category. However, I want to exclude the current product from that list which is not really working.

```
protected $_categoryFactory;
protected $_registry;
$collection = $this->getRelatedProductsCollection($result);
```

I am getting the current product and ID like that:

```
$product = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
$productId = $product->getId();
```

And then I tried to exclude it like that:

```
$collection ->removeItemByKey($productId);
$collection ->getSelect()->orderRand();
```

But I still can see the current product somewhere in the list. What do I need to change to exclude the current product?

Comment: You need to filter category product collection with not filter

Comment: Could you please explain further, I don't understand what you mean @BirenPatel

Comment: try $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['neq' => $productId]);

Comment: @jiheison Thank you it works! If you want create an answer and I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your collection to omit the current product using `addAttributeToFilter`.

E.g. by adding:

`$collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['neq' => $productId]);`